# How do I mirror the curve given below?

Tags: matlab, rotation, flip, mirror

I do not know whether which are the correct function, (eg. `flipud`, `fliplr`)
But I wish to mirror a curve as shown below:
[image]
TO

[image]

A

However, the I and V values are as follows:

```
I=
7.533307359
7.525186507
7.519095869
7.506914591
7.486612462
7.486612462
7.482552036
7.480521823
7.47849161
7.474431184
7.470370759
7.46428012
7.462249907
7.452098842
7.433826926
7.389162242
7.309983939
7.167869035
6.930334125
6.581137504
6.116218748
5.570091475
4.983359945
4.398658627
3.838319864
3.32670621
2.873968732
2.476047001
2.126850381
1.838560148
1.590874173
1.377701817
1.203103507
1.054897965
0.926994552
0.819393267
0.726003473
0.650885596
0.585918783
0.529072821
0.480347711
0.435683027
0.397108982
0.366655789
0.334172382
0.305749401
0.285447272
0.26311493
0.244843014
0.226571098
0.210329394
0.196117904
0.181906414
0.171755349
0.163634498
0.15145322
0.145362581
0.139271943
0.131151091
0.125060452
0.118969814
0.114909388
0.110848962
0.104758323
0.100697897
0.098667684
0.092577046
0.090546833
0.08851662
0.086486407
0.082425981
0.078365555
0.076335342
0.07430513
0.072274917
0.068214491
0.066184278
0.064154065
0.062123852
0.058063426
0.047912362
0.047912362
0.045882149
0.047912362
0.047912362
0.045882149
0.045882149
0.047912362
0.047912362
0.045882149
0.045882149
0.045882149
0.045882149
0.045882149
0.047912362
0.043851936
0.047912362
0.045882149
0.047912362
0.045882149
```

and

```
V=
0.599996469
2.099894456
3.569210247
5.00782203
6.446312
7.915719151
9.385065396
10.7932168
12.23198084
13.64010179
15.10944804
16.48692588
17.95630258
19.36433216
20.77223994
22.17975182
23.5255207
24.80912023
26.06067582
27.18810588
28.09951157
28.97908648
29.70498908
30.30847154
30.88170679
31.30260967
31.57133245
31.87149012
32.11115336
32.2905049
32.43985285
32.65094381
32.67893749
32.76855235
32.85847175
32.91808302
32.97790748
33.06861865
33.06764415
33.15862941
33.12728588
33.18784121
33.1872626
33.21741845
33.2169312
33.27773015
33.27742562
33.30770329
33.30742921
33.30715513
33.3069115
33.33731098
33.30648516
33.30633289
33.30621108
33.36725366
33.33654965
33.30584564
33.33633648
33.33624512
33.39737906
33.33609285
33.36664459
33.36655323
33.39710498
33.39707452
33.36637052
33.39695271
33.39692226
33.36627916
33.36621825
33.36615734
33.36612689
33.36609644
33.36606598
33.39661773
33.36597462
33.39655682
33.36591372
33.39646546
33.36570055
33.39631319
33.36567009
33.36570055
33.39631319
33.39628274
33.39628274
33.39631319
33.39631319
33.42689539
33.39628274
33.39628274
33.39628274
33.39628274
33.39631319
33.45747759
33.39631319
33.39628274
33.39631319
33.39628274
```

which is a 100x1 array for I and V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the answer in your question: just use `fliplr` function!
You need to use:

```
V1 = max(V) - fliplr(V)
I1 = fliplr(I)
plot(V1,I1);
```

[image]

The only important thing - it's easy to get mirror image, but when we have to locate it? (look at my yellow and blue curves).

This part `max(V)` defines curve shift for the x axis. It means if you use it just like you, new curve starts from 0 (red curve). If you need to shift it use `max(V) + 1` etc.

Comment: Hi Mikhail Sam, how do i mirror it with the same axis?
For example, i want both original and mirrored graphs to be of the same axis, (I) as yaxis and (V) as xaxis

Thanks in anyway!

Comment: Hi! Ahhh, I get it :) I create V(I) when you need I(V)! I will correct my answer!

Comment: @user5850017 Check it!

Comment: Thanks alot Mikhail Sam!